# What is the French word for "retrodict"?

Tags: traduction

I was wondering what was the French word for ***retrodict***, which means:

> [State a fact about the past based on inference or deduction, rather than evidence.](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/retrodict)

I looked up ***rétrodicter***, which seems to be used in some books, but no sign of it in any dictionary.

Comment: *Rétrodicter* would be the term if it was used. But in French although *rétrodiction* is used ([e.g.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causalit%C3%A9_(histoire)#La_r%C3%A9trodiction)) I have never seen *rétrodicter*. But if it were used it would be understood by analogy.

Comment: I've seen an occurence int the wiktionary https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9trodiction It's like prediction, but inverted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root of the verb "retrodict" is *retro* (past) and *predict*, which, as you rightly point out means State a fact about the past based on inference or deduction.
The concept of *Rétrodiction* is well-defined in french and is stated as:

**Rétrodiction**: la rétrodiction consiste à remonter des effets aux causes mais sans la possibilité de faire la démonstration expérimentale que tel phénomène entraîne nécessairement tel autre phénomène puisque l’événement est irrémédiablement révolu. (Antoine Prost, Douze leçons sur l'histoire, Paris, 1996, p. 173).

So, in its verb form, it would be **Rétrodicter**, although it must be extremely rare.

Comment: ***Rétrodicter**, inconnu* ! — ***Rétrodiction*** en passe de devenir un jargon de spécialiste https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=R%C3%A9trodiction%2Cr%C3%A9trodicter&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true#

Answer (score 3):

Si j'ai bien compris, il s'agit de raisonner pour remonter aux causes à partir des effets.

Aux échecs, cela s'appelle l'[analyse rétrograde](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyse_r%C3%A9trograde). Un exemple littéraire est [Le tableau du maître flamand](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Tableau_du_ma%C3%AEtre_flamand), d'Arturo Pérez-Reverte.

Je ne connais pas de verbe associé à cette démarche. Si j'avais à former un néologisme à partir de *rétrodiction* sur le modèle de *prédiction*, ce serait *rétrodire* plutôt que *rétrodicter*.

Answer (score 1):

*Rétrodiction/rétrodicter* dans le sens en question sont à mon avis mal adaptés au français, comme en témoigne par exemple [une autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/43897/25619). Ce n'est pas le sujet, mais on doit se rappeller que l'anglais a, morphologiquement parlant, *predict* et *dictate* mais pas dire, dicter et [prévoir](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3855), en plus de prédire. Ces différences font entre autres qu'il m'est plus naturel de voir l'élément *diction/dicter* non pas comme une partie de *prédire/prédiction* mais plutôt comme le nom et le verbe tel quel, donc diction, dicter vers/en/par l'arrière, à rebours ou je ne sais quoi. D'ailleurs à chaque fois que le terme est utilisé on se doit systématiquement de l'expliquer.

[Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrodiction) en anglais dit qu'on emploie aussi *postdiction* pour *retrodiction*. [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9trodiction) réserve l'emploi aux mathématiques en français et parle d'une « reconstitution probable d’une suite d’événements ayant eu lieu dans le passé ». On apprend aussi que le [*backtesting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtesting), ou [test retro-actif de validité](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtesting), est une forme de *retrodiction*. Or dans certains emplois spécialisés on trouve [*contrôle a posteriori*](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26534911) ou *ex post*. Rien n'empêche d'utiliser ces locutions adjectivales avec le terme *prédiction* (prédiction est-il vraiment l'antonyme de *retrodiction* ?).

Tel qu'on l'a évoqué [en commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40277/what-is-the-french-word-for-retrodict#comment80782_40277), on en discute en parlant de causalité en histoire, et on dit que la *retrodiction* « consiste à remonter des effets aux causes mais sans la possibilité de faire la démonstration expérimentale que tel phénomène entraîne nécessairement tel autre phénomène puisque l’événement est irrémédiablement révolu » ([Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causalit%C3%A9_(histoire)#La_r%C3%A9trodiction)). *Spéculer sur des faits/causes à partir des effets* me paraît une manière bien simple d'exprimer au moins une partie du concept. Si je dois définir un mot valise à chaque fois qu'il est employé, et mettre de côté mon intuition de locuteur concernant la valeur de ses éléments constitutifs, c'est pour moi un indice que ce terme est opaque et plutôt inutile ; ou trop récent et pas assez usuel, on verra avec le temps.

Ce qui explique que le nom *prédiction* suivi d'une locution adjectivale provenant du latin m'apparaîtra plus clair il me semble. Autrement j'écrirais le nom en entier avec le préfixe *rétro-* (« rétroprédiction », « rétroinférence ») pour éviter la confusion.